# Group IDs in SQL Server

Tags: sql

Hope all is well. I have a table with about 491,000 unique records in a SQL server database. I need to run these records against another table in Oracle database. The problem I have in Oracle is it can on filter 1000 records at a time. Here is the query and its error:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE1
WHERE ID IN(A LIST OF 1001 RECORDS)
```

> [Error] Script lines: 1-4 --------------------------
>    ORA-01795: maximum number of expressions in a list is 1000
>    Script line 3, statement line 3, column 11017

I can use the following query to run for couple thousand records but not sure how to do it with 491000 records.

```
SELECT ID
FROM TABLE2
WHERE (  ID IN(LIST OF 1000 RECORDS)
OR ID IN(LIST OF ANOTHER 1000 RECORDS)
OR ID IN(LIST OF ANOTHER 1000 RECORDS)
OR ID IN(LIST OF ANOTHER 1000 RECORDS))
```

Could anyone helpe me this this problem?

Many thanks

Forget to mention, I do not have privillage to create tables in Oracle database.

Comment: is there no rule to the ID's? like `between 1 and 491000`?

Comment: could you select all the rows from oracle and filter them in your application?

Comment: @April, I am running the query it now. it takes about two hours to pull those records Ahww, ahww

Comment: well, that's what `count(*)` and `where rownum < 1000` are for while testing something ;))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**

Since you can't create tables in your Oracle database, have you considered using a Linked Server to join straight from your SQL Server table to your Oracle table?

[How to set up and troubleshoot a linked server to an Oracle database in SQL Server](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/280106)

You could create the linked server using code similar to:

```
-- Adding linked server (from SQL Server Books Online):
/* sp_addlinkedserver [@server =] 'server' 
    [, [@srvproduct =] 'product_name']
    [, [@provider =] 'provider_name'] 
    [, [@datasrc =] 'data_source'] 
    [, [@location =] 'location'] [, [@provstr =] 'provider_string'] 
    [, [@catalog =] 'catalog']
*/ 

EXEC sp_addlinkedserver   'Ora817Link',  'Oracle',  'MSDAORA',  'oracle817'

-- Adding linked server login:
/* sp_addlinkedsrvlogin [@rmtsrvname =] 'rmtsrvname'
    [,[@useself =] 'useself']
    [,[@locallogin =] 'locallogin']
    [,[@rmtuser =] 'rmtuser']
    [,[@rmtpassword =] 'rmtpassword']
*/ 

EXEC sp_addlinkedsrvlogin 'Ora817Link', 'FALSE',NULL, 'scott', 'tiger'
```

Which would then allow you to perform a simple `join` between the two tables that reside on two different servers:

```
SELECT ot.ID
FROM 
    YourOracleServer...OracleTable ot
    JOIN SQLServerTable st ON ot.ID = st.ID
```

Comment: Thanks Mike, I forget to mention, I dont have privilage to create tables in Oracle database.

Comment: Thanks again Mike, I appreciate your quick help

Comment: These linked server codes are boyond my experience... Still trying to get the job done though.

Answer (score 0):

As @Aprillion mentionned, normally there would be a pattern for which ID's are relevant to fetch.

Suppose you have ID's for where the name is 'Bob', do this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE1
WHERE name = 'Bob'
```

If name is in another table, use a subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE1
WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM TABLE2 WHERE name = 'Bob');
```

Or a join:

```
SELECT TABLE1.*
FROM TABLE1 INNER JOIN TABLE2 ON TABLE1.ID=TABLE2.ID
WHERE name = 'Bob';
```